# Linq Group by Related Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, .net-core

I want to get the most items in their list
the sql query I want to run

```sql
select 
    i.Id, 
    count(*) as count
from Items
    inner join ItemItemList il on i.Id = il.ItemsId
group by i.Id
order by count desc
```

Item Entity

```
public  class Item:BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountedPrice{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemList> ItemLists { get; set; }
}
```

Item List Entity

```
public class ItemList:BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

my DTO

```
public class TopItemsInLists
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonId]
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

My Item repository

```
var query = _context.Items.Include(l => l.ItemLists)
            .GroupBy(g => g.ItemLists)
            .Select(z => new TopItemsInLists { ItemId = z.Key.ToString(), Quantity = z.Count() })
            .OrderByDescending(z => z.Quantity)
            .Take(10);
```

I want to get the most found items in the ItemLists.
Where am I doing wrong? If anyone has any other suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of grouping by collection property, you have to group by Id. Exactly as in SQL. But before that you have to multiply records by `SelectMany`.

```cs
var query = _context.Items
    .SelectMany(i => i.ItemLists, (i, il) => i)
    .GroupBy(i => i.Id)
    .Select(g => new TopItemsInLists { ItemId = g.Key.ToString(), Quantity = g.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(z => z.Quantity)
    .Take(10);
```

But I would suggest to use Query syntax for such constructions which is closer to the SQL:

```cs
var query = 
    from i in _context.Items
    from il in i.ItemLists 
    group i by i.Id into g 
    select new TopItemsInLists
    {
        ItemId = g.Key.ToString(), 
        Quantity = g.Count()
    };

query = query
    .OrderByDescending(z => z.Quantity)
    .Take(10);
```

Comment: Well, in addition to this, what should I do if I want to do it on a user basis. There is such a property in my user entity. do i need to do another from
public virtual ICollection<ItemList> ItemLists{ get; set; }

Comment: Probably, another `from` will add another `join` and apply records multiplication.

Comment: await (from l in _context.ItemLists
                                  from i in l.Items
                                  from u in _context.Users
                                  group new { i, u } by new TopItemsForUsers { ItemId = i.Id.ToString(), UserId = u.Id.ToString() }
                 into query

Comment: I get an error when I do from this way. "System.InvalidOperationException" .where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Grouping key is wrong. Create another question.

Comment: Okay. İ created new post. Thanks for help.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69766637/linq-group-by-relative-entites