# Linq Group by relative entites

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

My scenario: Users will be able to create lists and add items to these lists. What I want to do is to find the items in the lists created by the users at most.

Item Entity

```
public  class Item:BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountedPrice{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemList> ItemLists { get; set; }
}
```

Item List Entity

```
public class ItemList:BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

User Entity

```
public class User:BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Gsm { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemList> ItemLists{ get; set; }
}
```

my DTO

```
public class TopItemsForUsers
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonId]
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

My Item repository

```
var query = _context.Items.Include(l => l.ItemLists)
            .GroupBy(g => g.ItemLists)
            .Select(z => new TopItemsInLists { ItemId = z.Key.ToString(), Quantity = z.Count() })
            .OrderByDescending(z => z.Quantity)
            .Take(10);
```

I want to get products that are very present in users' lists
Where am I doing wrong? If anyone has any other suggestions

Comment: So, root of the query should be User?

Comment: My scenario: Users will be able to create lists and add items to these lists. What I want to do is to find the items in the lists created by the users at most.

Comment: I want to find the most common items in the lists created by users. I guess my root here should be user but I'm not sure

Comment: What does "at most" mean? What does "very present" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query. I hope I understand question correctly.

```cs
var query = 
    from u in _context.Users
    from il in u.ItemLists
    from i in il.Items
    group i by new { UserId = u.Id, ItemId = i.Id } into g 
    select new TopItemsInLists
    {
        UserId = g.Key.UserId.ToString(), 
        ItemId = g.Key.ItemId.ToString(), 
        Quantity = g.Count()
    };

query = query
    .OrderByDescending(z => z.Quantity)
    .Take(10);
```

Comment: Its done. Danyliv thank you.